# Probability Density of R

Tags: statistics

Can someone explain to me the last step in this calculation of a probability density function?

> $$P(R \in dr)=\frac{\pi(r+dr)^2-\pi r^2}{\pi} = 2r \, dr,$$ by ignoring
>   the term involving $(dr)^2$.

Why does it ignore $(dr)^2$? If it ignores $(dr)^2$, why not ignore $dr$ as well?

Comment: If $dr$ stands for first order change, $(dr)^2$ is second order and hence is noticeably smaller, so can be ignored

Comment: @gt6989b So if the probability is $P(R \in (dr)^2)$, would I still ignore $(dr)^2$ in the results? Or in this case, I only ignore $dr$?

Comment: No because you are then seeking 2nd order in the first place...